Can a bottom drawer common in mobile apps be used on mobile webpages?
I was trying out the GenAI features in Instagram, and loved how they used a drawer for hiding information a user doesn't need all the time. Can this pattern be implemented on web through either native OS functionalities or custom builds?
  

